# toggle something only once

Tags: javascript, html, css

im trying to make a javascript game but i ran into a problem,
i want to make sure that if a if statement = true it executes a function, this works now but it keeps executing it over and over again and i need it to only execute it once.

this is what i have now:

```
//this is the js
setInterval(function () {
    var characterTop = parseInt(
      window.getComputedStyle(character).getPropertyValue("top")
    )
    var characterLeft = parseInt(
      window.getComputedStyle(character).getPropertyValue("left")
    )
  
    if (characterTop > 200 && characterLeft > 700) {
      
      document.getElementById("win").classList.toggle("active")
      
      {stopMoveLeft();} 
      {stopMoveRight();}
      {stopMoveDown();} 
      {stopMoveUp();}   
    }
}, 50);
```

```
/*this is the css*/
#win {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    position: fixed;
    top: 600px;
    transition: all 500ms linear;

}

#win.active {
    top: 0px;
}
```

```
<!--this is the html-->
<div id="win"></div>
```

does anyone know how to make sure it keeps checking but only executes the function once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var intervalVar = setInterval(function () {
    var characterTop = parseInt(
      window.getComputedStyle(character).getPropertyValue("top")
    )
    var characterLeft = parseInt(
      window.getComputedStyle(character).getPropertyValue("left")
    )
  
    if (characterTop > 200 && characterLeft > 700) {
      
      document.getElementById("win").classList.toggle("active")
      
      {stopMoveLeft();} 
      {stopMoveRight();}
      {stopMoveDown();} 
      {stopMoveUp();}

      clearInterval(intervalVar);
    }
}, 50);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a boolean to check if it has ran the code already

```
var done = false;

//this is the js
setInterval(function () {
    var characterTop = parseInt(
      window.getComputedStyle(character).getPropertyValue("top")
    )
    var characterLeft = parseInt(
      window.getComputedStyle(character).getPropertyValue("left")
    )

    if (characterTop > 200 && characterLeft > 700 && !done) {
  
      done = true;
      document.getElementById("win").classList.toggle("active")
  
      {stopMoveLeft();} 
      {stopMoveRight();}
      {stopMoveDown();} 
      {stopMoveUp();}   
    }
}, 50);
```